# arraylist split("whitespace") and count the number of words

Tags: java

so I want to count the number of words in my `ArrayList`, currently I read lines from a file and saved those lines to the `ArrayList`.  
The file has

```
word    definition
a       alpha
b       bravo
c       charlie
d       delta
e       echo
f       foxtrot
```

so when I do arraylist.size() it prints 7. but I want to count the number of words.

my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WarmUp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = null;
        ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/dictionary.txt"));
            while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                elements.add(line);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

I think I can use split method 
so I thought this is the way

```
ArrayList<String> moreElements = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    String e = elements.get(i);
    moreElements.addAll(e.split(" "));

}
```

then call `moreElements.size()`
but I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: What's wrong with your solution that you think would work?

Comment: You are not closing the BufferedReader: `br.close()`

Comment: Start by printing the results of `e.split` and seeing what you're getting.

Comment: `split("\\s+")` this says to split on one or more spaces, you are only splitting on a single space as Pannu has stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Java 8 or higher you can use (assuming your List is called `elements`):

```
int count = elements.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.split("\\s+").length).sum();
```

Solution with a loop:

```
int count = 0;
for(String line : elements) {
  String[] tmp = line.split("\\s+"); //split on one or more spaces
  count += tmp.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) expects a list but [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) returns an array.
You must use [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) to convert the array to a list.
Also you must split by multiple spaces.
Change to this:

```
moreElements.addAll(Arrays.asList(e.split("\\s+")));
```